# Count the frequency of a specific character in a text input

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  char sentence;
  int count;

  cout << "Enter sentence: ";
  cin >> sentence;

  count = 0;
  while ( sentence == 'b' || 'B' ) {
    count++;
  }

  cout << "Number of b's: " << count * 1 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The counting must also stop at all punctuation. I can't seem to get it to give me the correct count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your `while` loop.  The variable `sentence` is not changed inside the loop, so the loop may execute forever.

You may want to use `std::string` for a sentence and `char` for a character in the sentence.

### Edit 1: Example

```
char letter;
cout << "Enter a sentence:\n";
while (cin >> letter)
{
  // Check for sentence termination characters.
  if ((letter == '\n') || (letter == '\r') || (letter == '.'))
  {
    break; // terminate the input loop.
  }
  // Put your letter processing code here.
} // End of while loop.
```

Comment: Hmm...I see. The problem, I think, is that we haven't gone over strings yet, so I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use them.

Comment: You need to input one character at a time until the User types in an end-of-line character.

Comment: Thomas, that seems similar to the instructions, actually. However, how would I check what the character is while the user is "`cin`-ing" the sentence?

Comment: Compare your character input to '\n' or '\r' or have the user enter some sentinel character such as '.'

Comment: Thomas, I'm very sorry...I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement that.

Comment: Please note that the above program terminates on the period character only, and will not stop on "all punctuation" as the problem requires.  Additionally, new line ('\n') and carriage return ('\r') will never be in the stream since they are omitted from console input.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple suspicious points in your program:

```
  char sentence;
  cin >> sentence;
```

This looks like it would only be reading one character. You might want to getline() and save user input in a std::string

As for

```
  while ( sentence == b || B ) {
```

This wouldn’t even compile since b and B are undefined. Maybe it should be

```
  if ( cur_byte == ‘b' || cur_byte == ‘B’ )
     count++
```

where cur_byte is some properly maintained *iterator* inside your string

Comment: Edited to include the 's around the b and B.

Comment: You need to say sentence == ‘b’ || sentence == ‘B’, otherwise your || will always be true - ‘B’ is a non-zero value, which is logically true in C/C++, so you have a possibly-true thing ORed with an always true thing which gives you true, regardless of sentence == ‘b'

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll try it with the various suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
```

Use string. `string sentence;` And create a for long as:

```
for(int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++)
if(sentence[i] == b || B) count ++;
```

So simple ;) Good luck ;)

EDIT 1:
If you will only use `while`:

```
int count = sentence.length();
int count2 = 0;
while(count != 0)
{
if(sentence[count] == b||B) count2++
count--;
}
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: I'm limited to only using `while`.

Comment: Then, count = sentence.length(); Wait. I am editing  the answer ;)

Comment: What's the purpose of `count--`?

Comment: it is same as starting from 0 and going up. With my way I am starting from the length of the sentence and I am going down ;)

Comment: So why not just start from 0 and go up as a b or B is found?

Comment: it is easier to do and you do with while loops... If you would use the for loop it is good to go up ;)

Comment: Telling me that `sentence` is not declared.

Comment: did you declare sentence as "string sentence;" also you need to cin>>sentence;

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter sentence: ";
    while (cin >> c && !ispunct(c)) if (tolower(c) == 'b') n++;
    cout << "Number of b's: " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

> Enter sentence: Two B or not two b, that is the question Bb.
>
> Number of b's: 2